# JButton разный цвет текста на одной кнопке

Tags: java, swing

Имеется `JButton`
Текст на кнопке задается двумя переменными

```
JButton btn = new JButton(number+" "+txt);
```

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы то что приходит с number было одного цвета, а то, что приходит с txt было другого цвета?

Answer (score 1):

Прошу прощения, решение оказалось до боли простым, на англ ресурсе подсмотрел. если кому нужно. html наше все

```
btn.setText("<html><span style=\"color:black\">"+number+"</span>   <span style=\"color:red\">"+txt+"</span></html>");
```